# What is the code to create unposted (upost-order) orders in progress 4gl language?

Tags: progress-4gl

What is the code to create unposted (upost-order) orders in progress 4gl language?

This is the code to find upost orders.

```
FIND upost-order WHERE
  upost-order.company = company AND
  upost-order.order-number = order.order-number
  NO-ERROR.

IF NOT AVAILABLE upost-order THEN
FIND upost-order WHERE
  upost-order.company = company AND
  upost-order.order-number =
  STRING(INTEGER(SUBSTRING(order.order-number,3,6)))
  NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean you want to know how to create a new record for this entity.
That would be

```
DO TRANSACTION:
   CREATE upost-order.
   /* Now if you want to assign arbitrary values to the key, */
   ASSIGN upost-order.company = company /* supposing you want to create for the same one you found */
          upost.order-number = cOrderNumber NO-ERROR. /* Whatever character value you want to assign to the number. */
 /* If you want to ask the user to input the values, on a GUI environment you could do this, instead of the ASSIGN above*/        
   UPDATE upost-order NO-ERROR.
/* You'll notice I used no-error in both. Now if an error happened, display it to the user */
   IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
        MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) VIEW-AS    ALERT-BOX.
        UNDO, LEAVE.
   END.
END.
```

Since I'm addressing more your question on how to create, of course the code above is not thorough or at its best. You could have more than one message, and in a transaction block, I'd probably name it, and prompt for the fields before creating and assigning, thus keeping the transaction at minimal time and as little as possible. 
I hope this helps with your question.